# How to update new image in the Tkinter after clearing an existing image.?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have 2 images in a folder named as 1.jgp , 2.jpg. I want to write a python code to display all the images one after another in the same location of the pane after 2 second delay. I tried to add the same code one after another with image 2.jpg, but it doesn't work. What changes do I need to make in this code to display image 2.jpg after 1.jpg is displayed and cleared. 
I have tried the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

root = Tk()
filename1="1.jpg"
filename2="2.jpg"
canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=800, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
image = Image.open(filename)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=photo)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tkinter's `after` function to call a function after a time delay. The function `itemconfig` can then be used on the canvas to take care of the actual changing of the image.

Something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class myGUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=800, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        filename="1.jpg"
        image = Image.open(filename)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.img = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=self.photo)

        self.root.after(2000, self.change_photo)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def change_photo(self):
        filename = "2.jpg"
        image = Image.open(filename)

        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.img, image=self.photo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = myGUI()
```

Comment: I tried to run the above code, it just displays 1.jpg and stays. No further update on the screen, just 1.jpg

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you get any error messages in the terminal?

Comment: No. It just opens 1.jpg, then I have to close the window and then the terminal gets back to the normal prompt. I have written your code in sublime and running on terminal.

Comment: It seems to work now. I have to display 100 images which are named similarily. I tried to put the statement which calls the change_photo() in a for loop but it doesn't work. How to achieve it ?

Comment: You can call self.root.after(2000, self.change_photo) at the end of change_photo and update some sort of counter on each call.

Comment: Thank You. I did as per your suggessgtion and it worked!